# how to apply a affine transformation to a single dot in PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

In PIL I have rotated a rectangle by an angle and pasted it back to the background image.
I'd like to know what will be the new coordinates of a specific corner.

function(old_coord) => new coordinates

I have read in the documentation it mentioned the center of rotation by default is the center of the image.

Here is my code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import os

background = Image.open('background.jpg')
rectangle = Image.open("rectangle.png")
my_angle = 30

rectangle_rotate = Image.Image.rotate(rectangle, angle=my_angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)

# box: 2-tuple giving the upper left corner
px = int(background.size[0] / 2)
py = int(background.size[1] / 2)
background.paste(im=rectangle_rotate,
                     box=(px, py),
                     mask=rectangle_rotate)
# The new position I'm getting is wrong, how come?????
pos_xNew = px * math.cos(math.radians(my_angle)) + py * math.sin(math.radians(my_angle))
pos_yNew = -px * math.sin(math.radians(my_angle)) + py * math.cos(math.radians(my_angle))
print('pos_xNew:', pos_xNew)
print('pos_yNew:', pos_yNew)
draw_img_pts = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
r = 10
# Drawing a simple small circle circle for visualization
draw_img_pts.ellipse((pos_xNew - r, pos_yNew - r, pos_xNew + r, pos_yNew + r), fill='red')

background.save('example_with_roatation.png')
```

how can I find the new coordinates value? I keep getting **wrong value**.

Background image (input):
[image: background]

Rectangle image (input):

[image: rectangle]

The Output I got with zero rotation as expected:

[image: zero rotation]

Output I got after 30 degree rotation:

[image: 30 degree rotation]

Comment: It would be helpful if you put back the `import` statements you have removed, if you shared your input and output images and showed what results you got and why/how they are wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell okay no problem, so I have posted my input files and output files.
I'd like to understand what am I missing. Thank you!

Comment: the problem is three part: 1) the rectangle is rotated around its top right corner 2) it is then clipped, introducing additional shift 3) the point is rotated around background's top left corner. To fix, you need to 1) rotate the point around the rectangle top right corner 2) calculate and add the rotational shift on top

Comment: @Marat thank you for your comment abd for pointing out where I have mistaken, but it's not clear for me how to do it.
Can you please share a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments inline

```
import math
import os

import numpy as np  # many operations are more concise in matrix form
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def get_rotation_matrix(angle):
    """ For background, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
    rotation is clockwise in traditional descartes, and counterclockwise, 
    if y goes down (as in picture coordinates)
    """
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
        [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])

def rotate(points, pivot, angle):
    """ Get coordinates of points rotated by a given angle counterclocwise 
    
    Args:
        points (np.array): point coordinates shaped (n, 2)
        pivot (np.array): [x, y] coordinates of rotation center
        angle (float): counterclockwise rotation angle in radians
    Returns:
        np.array of new coordinates shaped (n, 2)
    """
    relative_points = points - pivot
    return relative_points.dot(get_rotation_matrix(angle)) + pivot

background = Image.open('background.jpg')
rectangle = Image.open("rectangle.png")
my_angle_deg = 30
my_angle = math.radians(my_angle_deg)

rsize_x, rsize_y = rectangle.size
# to get shift introduced by rotation+clipping we'll need to rotate all four corners
# starting from top-right corners, counter-clockwise
rectangle_corners = np.array([
    [rsize_x, 0],  # top-right
    [0, 0],  # top-left
    [0, rsize_y],  # bottom-left
    [rsize_x, rsize_y]  # bottom-right
])
# rectangle_corners now are:
# array([[262,   0],
#       [  0,   0],
#       [  0,  67],
#       [262,  67]])

rotated_corners = rotate(rectangle_corners, rectangle_corners[0], my_angle)
# as a result of rotation, one of the corners might end up left from 0,
# e.g. if the rectangle is really tall and rotated 90 degrees right
# or, leftmost corner is no longer at 0, so part of the canvas is clipped
shift_introduced_by_rotation_clip = rotated_corners.min(axis=0)

rotated_shifted_corners = rotated_corners - shift_introduced_by_rotation_clip

# finally, demo
# this part is just copied from the question
rectangle_rotate = Image.Image.rotate(rectangle, angle=my_angle_deg, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)

# box: 2-tuple giving the upper left corner
px = int(background.size[0] / 2)
py = int(background.size[1] / 2)
background.paste(im=rectangle_rotate,
                     box=(px, py),
                     mask=rectangle_rotate)

# let's see if dots land right after these translations:
draw_img_pts = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
r = 10
for point in rotated_shifted_corners:
    pos_xNew, pos_yNew = point + [px, py]
    draw_img_pts.ellipse((pos_xNew - r, pos_yNew - r, pos_xNew + r, pos_yNew + r), fill='red')
```

[image]